# Одинаковые элементы в разных столбцах

Tags: excel

Как можно средствами Excel проверить сколько элементов столбца A содержится в столбце B ?
Именно узнать количество, а не сравнить одинаковые значения. Речь идет о числах. Вообще идея такова: узнать процент совпадающих элементов столбцов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формула массива:

```
=СУММ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B1:B10;A1:A10))
```

Формула массива вводится одновременным нажватием *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. Формула должна заключиться в фигурные скобки - *{=формула}*

Формула считает все совпадения. Т.е. если в столбце *А* два одинаковых значения, счет будет произведен для каждого из них.